# POST json data (stored as json files in ADLS) to REST endpoint in Azure Data factory

Tags: json, rest, post, azure-data-factory

I have a requirement to POST json data (stored as json files in ADLS) to REST API endpoint. I have to use Azure Data factory for this.  I have gone through Microsoft documentation but unable to get a clear idea on it is implementation.
As per my understanding ADF Data Copy activity doesn't support REST API as output/sink service.

Reaching out if anyone could help me with any documentation or reference material that could guide me to implement this. Thanks!

Comment: Just use Web activity and POST or PUT?

Answer (score 1):

I have repro’d with sample API and was able to post the JSON data from blob storage to the REST endpoint using data flow activity in azure data factory.

Source dataset:

[image]

- Connect source to json dataset.

[image]

- Connect sink to rest endpoint.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks!!, I tried the same for my use case, but when I test the connection of the sink, I get the error "DFExecutorUserError". Could you help me understand and resolve this. Also wanted to know the integration run time you are using while creating the linked service for sink, is it Azure or Self-hosted ? I understand with Rest APIs we need to use Self hosted.

Comment: Also when I try to validate the data flow, I get this message in the Output : Linked Service with Self hosted IR is not supported in data flow. Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

ADF has the "REST as the Source" and "REST as the sink". You can check the details on the following page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-rest?tabs=data-factory

I have created the pipeline with sample API and was able to post the JSON data from blob storage to the REST endpoint using copy activity in Azure data factory.

Linked Service:
[Rest Service as Linked Service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eb56J.png)
Dataset:
[Rest data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LY1JG.png)
Copy Activity Source:
[Copy activity source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2Bxh.png)
Copy Activity Sink:
[Copy activity sink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eD3iH.png)